# Combining different feature extraction methods with different ml models

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I have 4 feature extraction ways and 3 ml models. Now I am trying to make all the combinations possible, so it'll give me 12 combinations eg. M1 with Feat1, M1 with Feat2 and so on.
I tried writing a class for it, however I am stuck. Below is my code:

```
class Ensemble:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit_transform(self,X, index):
        if index == 0:
            vec = DictVectorizer()
            return vec.fit_transform(X), vec
        elif index == 1:
            hashed_data = []
            for instance in X:
                hashed_instance = {}
                for key, value in instance.items():
                    hashed_key = "_".join(key)
                    hashed_instance[hashed_key] = value
                hashed_data.append(hashed_instance)

            hasher = FeatureHasher(n_features=10, input_type="dict")
            return hasher.fit_transform(hashed_data), hasher
        elif index == 2:
            flattened_data = [list(d.keys()) for d in X]
            encoder = MultiLabelBinarizer()
            return encoder.fit_transform(flattened_data), encoder
        elif index == 3:
            flattened_data = [" ".join(["_".join(key) for key in d.keys()]) for d in X]
            vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
            return vectorizer.fit_transform(flattened_data), vectorizer
    
    def transform(self,X, index,feat):
        if index == 0:
            return feat.transform(X)
        elif index == 1:
            hashed_data = []
            for instance in X:
                hashed_instance = {}
                for key, value in instance.items():
                    hashed_key = "_".join(key)
                    hashed_instance[hashed_key] = value
                hashed_data.append(hashed_instance)

            return feat.transform(hashed_data)
        elif index == 2:
            flattened_data = [list(d.keys()) for d in X]
            return feat.transform(flattened_data)
        elif index == 3:
            flattened_data = [" ".join(["_".join(key) for key in d.keys()]) for d in X]
            return feat.transform(flattened_data)

    def fit(self,X, y_train):
        models = [LogisticRegression(),KNeighborsClassifier(),RandomForestClassifier()]
        feats = list(range(4))
        fmodels = list(itertools.product(models, feats))
        self.fitted_models = []
        for model, feat_ex in fmodels:
            X_train, feat = self.fit_transform(X, feat_ex)
            self.fitted_models.append((model.fit(X_train, y_train),feat_ex ,feat))
    
    def predict(self,X):
        self.predictions = []
        for model, feat_ex ,feat in self.fitted_models:
            X_test = self.transform(X, feat_ex,feat)
            self.predictions.append(model.predict(X_test))

        print(self.predictions)


model = Ensemble()
model.fit(X,y_train)
model.predict(X_val)
```

And here's the error I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[174], line 74
     72 model = Ensemble()
     73 model.fit(X,y_train)
---> 74 model.predict(X_val)

Cell In[174], line 67, in Ensemble.predict(self, X)
     65     X_test = self.transform(X, feat_ex,feat)
     66     # print("---test--",X_test.shape)
---> 67     self.predictions.append(model.predict(X_test))
     69 print(self.predictions)

File c:\Users\Admin'\Desktop\Course exercises\fokg_miniproject_final\.env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py:451, in LinearClassifierMixin.predict(self, X)
    437 """
    438 Predict class labels for samples in X.
    439 
   (...)
    448     Vector containing the class labels for each sample.
    449 """
    450 xp, _ = get_namespace(X)
--> 451 scores = self.decision_function(X)
    452 if len(scores.shape) == 1:
    453     indices = xp.astype(scores > 0, int)
...
    415         f"X has {n_features} features, but {self.__class__.__name__} "
    416         f"is expecting {self.n_features_in_} features as input."
    417     )

ValueError: X has 3077 features, but LogisticRegression is expecting 423 features as input.
```

I tried to debug it however, I can't seem to understand why it's giving me this error. I tried storing the instances of feature extraction modules, but that also isn't working.

Comment: this is not complete code, maybe you are using the wrong variables in fit: model.fit(X,y_train)

Comment: The complete code is a lot bigger, but I am sure that I am using correct variables.

Comment: Then you would not get an error, explain then why you train and test sets have different feature dimensionality.